# UIcollectionView.VisibleCell().count method returns 0 although cells are visibile in the simulator

Tags: ios, swift

```
func prepareVisibleCellsForAnimation() {

        print("\(self.peopleCollectionView.visibleCells().count)")

//THIS ALWAYS RETURNS 0 ALTHOUGH THE CELLS ARE CLEARY VISIBLE IN THE SIMULATOR

        for i in 0..<self.peopleCollectionView!.visibleCells().count {

            let cell: PeopleViewCell =  self.peopleCollectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: i, inSection: 0)) as! PeopleViewCell

            cell.frame = CGRectMake(-CGRectGetWidth(cell.bounds), cell.frame.origin.y, CGRectGetWidth(cell.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(cell.bounds))

            cell.alpha = 0.0


        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried calling that statement, somewhere outside "func prepareVisibleCellsForAnimation()"? If it's returning 0, then the problem is probably wherever you're calling the statement, in this case the function inside which you're calling it.

Comment: yes, i have called in a func called animateCells and in viewdidAppear.

Comment: my actual problem is that mycustomCollectionView.visibleCells() is empty in viewWillAppear and ViewDidLoad but is returns the proper Count in viewDidAppear.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the collectionView is still reloading.
Make sure to call `layoutIfNeeded` after the reload:

```
collectionView.reloadData()
collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()

print(collectionView.visibleCells.count) // Result > 0
```